# create products on the fly with search keyword?

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

In front-end search when a user searches with any keyword I need to call xyz API, it will return items based on this keyword.

Now I need to create products on the fly in Magento if those items not exist, otherwise, I need to update price.

Then I need to show the results in search result page based on the keyword as usual.

I followed link
https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1121

But I'm not able to figure it out where I need to write my logic.